# How can I find the limit of this recursive sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series

$a_0 \in (0,1)$; $a_{k+1} = a_k - \frac{1}{2}a_k^2$; Want to find $\lim_{k \to \infty} ka_k$.

It is not too difficult to show $a_k \to 0$ as $k \to \infty$ using the monotone convergence theorem.  But I cannot seem to make any further progress.  Attempting to find $a_k$ in terms of $a_0$ by induction seems difficult.

Comment: See this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/49691/1242

Answer (score 0):

First, one can easily show that $a_k \neq 0$ for every $k$. Hence, one has
$$\frac{1}{a_{k+1}} - \frac{1}{a_k} = \frac{1}{a_k - \frac{1}{2}a_k^2} - \frac{1}{a_k}= \frac{1}{a_k} \left( \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{2}a_k}-1\right)$$

and because $a_k \rightarrow 0$, you get from here the following expansion
$$\frac{1}{a_{k+1}} - \frac{1}{a_k} = \frac{1}{a_k} \left( 1 + \frac{1}{2}a_k + o(a_k)-1\right)  = \frac{1}{2} + o(1)$$

Hence, the sequence $\displaystyle{\left(\frac{1}{a_{k+1}} - \frac{1}{a_k} \right)}$ tends to $\displaystyle{\frac{1}{2}}$ : you can now use Cesaro's theorem with this sequence, to get that
$$\lim_{k \rightarrow +\infty} \frac{1}{ka_k}   = \frac{1}{2}$$

and finally,
$$\boxed{\lim_{k \rightarrow +\infty} ka_k  = 2}$$